# Loopless submatrix assignment in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-indexing, submatrix

I have a matrix `F` of size `D-by-N` and a vector `A` of length `N` of random integers in the range `[1,a]`. I want to create a matrix `M` of size `D * a` such that each colum `M(:,i)` has the vector `F(:,i)` starting from the index `(A(i)-1)*D+1` to `(A(i)-1)*D+D`.

Example:

```
F = [1 2 3 10
     4 5 6 22]

A = [3 2 1 2]

a = 4

M = [0 0 3 0
     0 0 6 0
     0 2 0 10
     0 5 0 22
     1 0 0 0
     4 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0]
```

I can do it with a simple loop

```
        for i = 1 : N
            M((A(i)-1)*D+1:(A(i)-1)*D+D,i) = F(:,i);
        end
```

but for large `N` this might take a while. I am looking for a way to do it without loop.

Comment: I'd argue that this is quite fast.  Did you even time it for large values of `a / N` to check to see if your statement is correct?

Comment: Well, it's not really slow, but I would like something faster if possible, because this part of my code is run at each iteration of my main algorithm. On my computer it takes `3s` when `a = 3`, `D = 6` and `N = 1e6`.

Comment: How can `a` be `4` if `A = [3 2 1 2]`? `A` has elements from `1` to `3`.

Comment: @Divakar Some values can be missing, since they are randomly sampled. In that case (4 is missing) the bottom part of the matrix will be 0 (in the example, the last two rows).

Comment: Makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a `linear-indexing` based approach -

```
[D,N] = size(F);    %// Get size of F

start_idx = (A-1)*D+1 + [0:N-1]*D*a;          %// column start linear indices
all_idx = bsxfun(@plus,start_idx,[0:D-1]');   %//'# all linear indices

out = zeros(D*a,N); %// Initialize output array with zeros
out(all_idx) = F;   %// Insert values from F into output array
```

Sample run -

```
F =
     1     2     3    10
     4     5     6    22
A =
     3     2     1     2
a =
     4
out =
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     6     0
     0     2     0    10
     0     5     0    22
     1     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is really fast (10 times faster than my loop). However, it gives incorrect results if, for instance, all elements of `A` are ones. I am testing using
`D = 2;
N = 1e2;
a = 4;
F = rand(D,N);
A = ones(1,N);`

Comment: @Simon Oh I assumed `A` would be `1:N`, my bad! Could you add an example with something not as simple as `[1,2,3]` into the question as sample?

Comment: You are right, the example in the question was too trivial and did not make clear that `A` contains random integer in the range `[1,a]`. I edited my question.

Comment: @Simon Edited my solution accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! The larger `N`, the faster your code is compared to my loop. For `N = 1e6` it is 10 times faster!

Comment: Nice job buddy.  Another example of a question with an initially oversimplified example. I couldn't figure out how to do it with `sparse` with the new formulation so I just deleted my answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Yup and that's why I had to change my solution too entirely.